# ArcGIS Mosaic to New Raster() tool seems to interpolate data gaps on one computer/version but not another?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster, mosaic

i have a group of raster files in .tif format that I want to mosaic together into one .tif.

I've noticed that I get data gaps along the seams when I do Mosaic to New Raster() on my home computer (ArcMap 10.1). Also, these data gaps are not necessarily where there is no data because when I display the original .tif files, there is coverage where the final mosaic-ed raster shows "no data" values. There should be some gaps because the original rasters do not completely overlap, but there is more coverage than what is shown here as gaps. Here is a screen shot of the mosaic-ed raster with the data gaps:

[image]

Then, when I do the same operation on the same rasters in the same order, but on a different computer (ArcMap 10), there are no gaps at all. Here is a screen shot of the mosiac-ed raster in the same region as above:

[image]

Ideally, I would like a final single raster with no data gaps so I would like to use the no gap raster, but is it reliable? I've read that Mosaic to New Raster does not interpolate the no data areas, so what could be going on? How do I know which final layer is reliable?

Comment: I've no idea what's going on, just guesses. Do the source rasters have identical projections on both machines? is the output projection identical on both? If there is a coordinate transform involved in one and and the other you might see something like this. 2nd thing to look at, paying close attention to detail, is the Geoprocessing Environment settings on each machine (under "Geoprocessing" tool menu).